# Iterate folders and files on Google Drive without authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, google-drive-api

Google's Drive service is great, but their documentation is quite confusing...
What I want to do is to create a portfolio site where upon request I fetch all files contained in a particular folder from my Google Drive (e.g. a photo gallery). This requires iterating through an amount of subfolders and store the file data in a JS object, XML feed or similar. Language is not so important. Simply using the "Publish to the web" feature won't do as I can only make manual requests and they're very limited.
I've tried to use the Files: list provided in the SDK but it won't work without requiring OAuth 2. Found out that its possible to make a "domain-wide delegation of authority" and bypass its authorization but that would require me to set up a Google Apps domain. Seriously, all that to fetch some files?
My best guess now is to use the https://googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly scope, but from there I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Why you're not storing the folder's id and just query for `"<id>" in parents` to list all the children?

Comment: Sounds interesting, do you have any example of how I would do that? I'm very new to Google's APIs.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list